# Dynamic mongodb query generation with Node.js driver by passing match clause from web page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dynamic

I'm trying to pass query dynamically as above.I have 2 text fields and submit button. When I click on submit button nothing is happening. Following is my
app.js content (to make db connection . portware_ants is the db name)

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/portware_ants');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
req.db = db;
next();
});
```

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

index.js file content

```
 router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
 var db = req.db;
 var users = db.get('users');
 var col_name=req.params.colname;
 var col_value=req.params.colvalue;
 var query={};
 query[col_name]=col_value;
 users.find(query,{limit: 10000},function(e, docs){
 res.render('users', { 
  title: 'Users',
  'users': docs     
});
});
});
```

users.ejs content (I'm not using jade )

```
 <body >  
 <% include partials/nav %>
 <h1>Portware Orders by Symbol TCA Report</h1>
 <form name="getuser",method="post",action="/users">
 Column name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="colname">
<br>
Column value:<br>
<input type="text" name="colvalue">  
<button type="submit" value="Search" class="submitButton">Search</button>
</form>  
<div id="table-scroll" >
<table   align="center">
<tr style="width:200px">
<th>Symbol</th>
<th>Order_id</th>
</tr>
<% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
<tr style="width:100%">
<td ><%= user.symbol %></td>
<td><%= user.order_id %></td>
</tr>
<% }); %>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

I have created two text fields and a button . On click of the button URL becomes http://localhost:3000/users?colname=symbol&colvalue=USD%2FJPY but I dont see filter is working.
Please help me to find the issue

Comment: What's your users schema like? What are the values of `req.params.colname` and `req.params.colvalue` that would make the query object bring valid results?

Comment: Users is the collection which has around 15 columns.From web page I'm passing req.params.colname as 'symbol' (which is one of the column in the collection) and req.params.colvalue as 'USD/INR'. When I hit the submit button my URL becomes http://localhost:3000/users?colname=symbol&colvalue=USD%2FINR . But I dont see the report is filtered with symbol:'USD/INR'

Comment: Can you please [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30125210/edit) your question to include the salient details like the actual users schema, how you are connecting to your db etc, not in the comments?

Comment: Thanks Chridam I have updated the original post

Comment: In your mongodb, have you tried querying it with some test values like `db.users.find({symbol:'USD/INR'}) `?

Comment: yes I did and its working . Moreover when i hard-code colname and colvalue as symbol and USD/INR respectively in index.js file ,filtering is working

Comment: I managed it to work. thanks for your time chridam.